# How do I start debugging a Sinatra app in production?

Tags: ruby, debugging, amazon-ec2, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app. It takes a URL via a POST request, processes that URL and returns a code.

It works fine on my local machine through a Curl call:

```
curl --data-urlencode "path=PATH_HERE" localhost:4567/process
```

And it returns a JSON response.

However, once it's on production (EC2) I do a similar POST request:

```
curl --insecure --data-urlencode "path=PATH_HERE" https://faxattach.staging.myaidin.com/process
```

However, it doesn't return anything. The traffic is definitely going to the EC2 machine, which tcpdump confirms, but I'm not sure if it's actually hitting the Sinatra app.

How would I check if it is hitting the Sinatra app? The log files remain unchanged, checked using `tail -f`. And, if it's not hitting the app, how would I start investigating the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is the port. By default HTTP requests go to port 80. You can run your app on that port to fix the problem with:

```
rackup -p 80
```

Comment: Even if it's SSL? (note the https in the POST request)

Comment: Looks like it's definitely going through port 443 from tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

Your need to change the security policy and allow traffic to port 4567.

Or, as @ismael has suggested, you can run the Rack server on port 80. This would require root privileges and you might need to use `sudo rackup -p 80` or `rvmsudo rackup -p 80`.